# Html canvas not working for e-signature in simple webpage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is my first HTML code. i m trying to put a canvas where user can put e signature by his mouse. Can anyone help me where im wrong. The html and css part works but e signature is not showing on the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>eSignature Page</title>
    <style>
        .wrapper {
            position: relative;
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .signature-pad {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('signature-pad');
        function resizeCanvas() {
            var ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
            canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
            canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
            canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
        }
        window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
        resizeCanvas();
        var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
        });
        document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function () {
            signaturePad.clear();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One thing is you need to keep your entire <script>...</script> just before the closing tag of </body>

Comment: Also can I know what is `SignaturePad` ?

Answer (score 0):

### There is this point :

- You seem to use this [external library](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) but you don't load it on
  your code

You need to load it, the simplest way is to load it from the CDN

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
```

---

After as you specify the background-color in your css :

```
.signature-pad {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white; // <----- Here
}
```

Hence, you don't need to add the option when you create your signaturePad :

```
// BEFORE
const signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
});

// AFTER
const signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
```

---

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('signature-pad');

function resizeCanvas() {
    const ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * ratio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * ratio;
    canvas.getContext("2d").scale(ratio, ratio);
}

window.onresize = resizeCanvas;
resizeCanvas();

const signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function () {
    signaturePad.clear();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.signature-pad {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightgrey; // For visualisation puropse, I changed it
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>eSignature Page</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signature_pad@2.3.2/dist/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```